Japanese horror show/movie with an 'episode' about a cartoon 'cat'
I used to watch this show; I do not remember the name.
There was this episode about a kid that gets bullied at school, and one day he receives an odd email or something analogous on his computer that leads to an animation.
In the first episode of the animation: He is getting bullied by a pair of classmates before a magic cat shows up to his aid, so it takes a picture of one of the bullies, and turns the picture into a puzzle so the cat sort of rearranges the bullie (all comical and cartoonish), the bullies then decide to run off since they are 'messed up' by the magic puzzle.
The next day, he goes to school and the bullies are missing, their bodies later to be found by the police. One day where he is very upset at mostly everyone he knows (parents, friends, etc), on that day he watches the second episode: He can be seen to be very upset at everyone (as in real life), so the cat helps him turn everyone that he is upset at into food that he liked.
Afterwards, there is an explosion at a 'circus'/theme park thing where all the people in the cartoon that had turned to 'food' had died (including his parents). He is very upset about this, so when he watches the last episode: he asks the cat to bring everyone back, which it does.
The episode ends, and then he can hear sort of zombified voices in the hallway and knocks on his door.

After searching the internet, I was able to find information about it.
The show was called "Prayer Beads (Omoinotama)"; it's the episode 8, "Cat's Paw".
